# Claiming 1-1 Correspondence.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two infinite sets $S$ and $T$ and $T$ is countably infinite. Suppose that I can establish a correspondence between all but a countably infinite number of elements in $S$ and the elements in $T$. How can I better describe this relationship between $S$ and $T$? Is there a way to establish a bijection between the two sets? Thanks, I am awfully new to most of this.

Comment: Do you mean you have a bijection $S\setminus N \to T$ where $N$ is countably infinite?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: By correspondence do you mean $1-1$ correspondence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $S = (S\setminus N) \cup N$ where $N$ is countably infinite and you have a bijection $S\setminus N \to T$. As $T$ is countably infinite, $S\setminus N$ is countably infinite. So $S$ is the union of two countably infinite sets and is therefore countably infinite.

Comment: Ok so since $S$ is countably infinite, can I claim that there is a bijection between $S$ and the set of positive integers?

Comment: This is often the definition of countably infinite. I can add to my answer if I haven't answered all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot conclude that there is a bijection under your conditions: consider the sets {$1$} and $\mathbb Z$. Then you can assign $ 1 \rightarrow 1$ , and still have countably-infinite elements unmatched in the target. If you can, though, find an injection  h:$ S \rightarrow T $ and an injection g:$T \rightarrow S $  , then you can conclude there is a bijection between the two sets. This last is the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem.